# How to free memory from minHeap C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, dijkstra

I have an implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-algorithm-for-adjacency-list-representation-greedy-algo-8/ but there is significant memory leaks when I try to use it. The problem is with the minHeap according to when I run it with valgrind. I have tried freeing each pointer  like:

```
for (int i=0; i<size; i+=1){
    free(minHeap->array[i]);
}
```

but valgrind gives invalid free() and the leak is not solved. Here is the Dijkstra's code.

```
// C++ program for Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm for adjacency 
// list representation of graph 

#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <limits.h> 
#include <float.h>

// A structure to represent a node in adjacency list 
struct AdjListNode 
{ 
    int dest; 
    double weight; 
    struct AdjListNode* next; 
}; 

// A structure to represent an adjacency list 
struct AdjList 
{ 
    struct AdjListNode *head;  // pointer to head node of list 
}; 

// A structure to represent a graph. A graph is an array of adjacency lists. 
// Size of array will be V (number of vertices in graph) 
struct Graph 
{ 
    int V; 
    struct AdjList* array; 
}; 

// A utility function to create a new adjacency list node 
struct AdjListNode* newAdjListNode(int dest, double weight) 
{ 
    struct AdjListNode* newNode = (struct AdjListNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct AdjListNode)); 
    newNode->dest = dest; 
    newNode->weight = weight; 
    newNode->next = NULL; 
    return newNode; 
} 

// A utility function that creates a graph of V vertices 
struct Graph* createGraph(int V) 
{ 
    struct Graph* graph = (struct Graph*) malloc(sizeof(struct Graph)); 
    graph->V = V; 

    // Create an array of adjacency lists.  Size of array will be V 
    graph->array = (struct AdjList*) malloc(V * sizeof(struct AdjList)); 

     // Initialize each adjacency list as empty by making head as NULL 
    for (int i = 0; i < V; ++i) 
        graph->array[i].head = NULL; 

    return graph; 
} 

// Adds an edge to an undirected graph 
void addEdge(struct Graph* graph, int src, int dest, double weight) 
{ 
    // Add an edge from src to dest.  A new node is added to the adjacency 
    // list of src.  The node is added at the beginning 
    struct AdjListNode* newNode = newAdjListNode(dest, weight); 
    newNode->next = graph->array[src].head; 
    graph->array[src].head = newNode; 

    // Since graph is undirected, add an edge from dest to src also 
    newNode = newAdjListNode(src, weight); 
    newNode->next = graph->array[dest].head; 
    graph->array[dest].head = newNode; 
} 

// Structure to represent a min heap node 
struct MinHeapNode 
{ 
    int  v; 
    double dist; 
}; 

// Structure to represent a min heap 
struct MinHeap 
{ 
    int size;      // Number of heap nodes present currently 
    int capacity;  // Capacity of min heap 
    int *pos;     // This is needed for decreaseKey() 
    struct MinHeapNode **array; 
}; 

// A utility function to create a new Min Heap Node 
struct MinHeapNode* newMinHeapNode(int v, double dist) 
{ 
    struct MinHeapNode* minHeapNode = (struct MinHeapNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct MinHeapNode)); 
    minHeapNode->v = v; 
    minHeapNode->dist = dist; 
    return minHeapNode; 
} 

// A utility function to create a Min Heap 
struct MinHeap* createMinHeap(int capacity) 
{ 
    struct MinHeap* minHeap = (struct MinHeap*) malloc(sizeof(struct MinHeap)); 
    minHeap->pos = (int *)malloc(capacity * sizeof(int)); 
    minHeap->size = 0; 
    minHeap->capacity = capacity; 
    minHeap->array = 
         (struct MinHeapNode**) malloc(capacity * sizeof(struct MinHeapNode*)); 
    return minHeap; 
} 

// A utility function to swap two nodes of min heap. Needed for min heapify 
void swapMinHeapNode(struct MinHeapNode** a, struct MinHeapNode** b) 
{ 
    struct MinHeapNode* t = *a; 
    *a = *b; 
    *b = t; 
} 

// A standard function to heapify at given idx 
// This function also updates position of nodes when they are swapped. 
// Position is needed for decreaseKey() 
void minHeapify(struct MinHeap* minHeap, int idx) 
{ 
    int smallest, left, right; 
    smallest = idx; 
    left = 2 * idx + 1; 
    right = 2 * idx + 2; 

    if (left < minHeap->size && 
        minHeap->array[left]->dist < minHeap->array[smallest]->dist ) 
      smallest = left; 

    if (right < minHeap->size && 
        minHeap->array[right]->dist < minHeap->array[smallest]->dist ) 
      smallest = right; 

    if (smallest != idx) 
    { 
        // The nodes to be swapped in min heap 
        MinHeapNode *smallestNode = minHeap->array[smallest]; 
        MinHeapNode *idxNode = minHeap->array[idx]; 

        // Swap positions 
        minHeap->pos[smallestNode->v] = idx; 
        minHeap->pos[idxNode->v] = smallest; 

        // Swap nodes 
        swapMinHeapNode(&minHeap->array[smallest], &minHeap->array[idx]); 

        minHeapify(minHeap, smallest); 
    } 
} 

// A utility function to check if the given minHeap is ampty or not 
int isEmpty(struct MinHeap* minHeap) 
{ 
    return minHeap->size == 0; 
} 

// Standard function to extract minimum node from heap 
struct MinHeapNode* extractMin(struct MinHeap* minHeap) 
{ 
    if (isEmpty(minHeap)) 
        return NULL; 

    // Store the root node 
    struct MinHeapNode* root = minHeap->array[0]; 

    // Replace root node with last node 
    struct MinHeapNode* lastNode = minHeap->array[minHeap->size - 1]; 
    minHeap->array[0] = lastNode; 

    // Update position of last node 
    minHeap->pos[root->v] = minHeap->size-1; 
    minHeap->pos[lastNode->v] = 0; 

    // Reduce heap size and heapify root 
    --minHeap->size; 
    minHeapify(minHeap, 0); 

    return root; 
} 

// Function to decreasy dist value of a given vertex v. This function 
// uses pos[] of min heap to get the current index of node in min heap 
void decreaseKey(struct MinHeap* minHeap, int v, double dist) 
{ 
    // Get the index of v in  heap array 
    int i = minHeap->pos[v]; 

    // Get the node and update its dist value 
    minHeap->array[i]->dist = dist; 

    // Travel up while the complete tree is not hepified. 
    // This is a O(Logn) loop 
    while (i && minHeap->array[i]->dist < minHeap->array[(i - 1) / 2]->dist) 
    { 
        // Swap this node with its parent 
        minHeap->pos[minHeap->array[i]->v] = (i-1)/2; 
        minHeap->pos[minHeap->array[(i-1)/2]->v] = i; 
        swapMinHeapNode(&minHeap->array[i],  &minHeap->array[(i - 1) / 2]); 

        // move to parent index 
        i = (i - 1) / 2; 
    } 
} 

// A utility function to check if a given vertex 
// 'v' is in min heap or not 
bool isInMinHeap(struct MinHeap *minHeap, int v) 
{ 
   if (minHeap->pos[v] < minHeap->size) 
     return true; 
   return false; 
} 

// The main function that calulates distances of shortest paths from src to all 
// vertices. It is a O(ELogV) function 
void dijkstra(struct Graph* const graph, vector<double> &dist, vector<double> const &max, vector<double> const &P_s, const int src){
    int size = graph->V;

    // minHeap represents set E 
    struct MinHeap* minHeap = createMinHeap(size); 

    // Initialize min heap with all vertices. dist value of all vertices  
    for (int v = 0; v < size; ++v) 
    { 
        // Testing different initialization
        dist[v] = max[v];
        // Make dist value of src vertex as 0 so that it is extracted first 
        if (v==src){
            dist[v] = 0;
        }
        minHeap->array[v] = newMinHeapNode(v, dist[v]); 
        minHeap->pos[v] = v; 
    }
    decreaseKey(minHeap, src, dist[src]); 

    // Initially size of min heap is equal to size 
    minHeap->size = size; 

    // In the followin loop, min heap contains all nodes 
    // whose shortest distance is not yet finalized. 
    while (!isEmpty(minHeap)) 
    { 
        // Extract the vertex with minimum distance value 
        struct MinHeapNode* minHeapNode = extractMin(minHeap); 
        int u = minHeapNode->v; // Store the extracted vertex number 

        // Traverse through all adjacent vertices of u (the extracted 
        // vertex) and update their distance values
        struct AdjListNode* pCrawl = graph->array[u].head; 
        while (pCrawl != NULL) 
        { 
            int v = pCrawl->dest;

            // If shortest distance to v is not finalized yet, and distance to v 
            // through u is less than its previously calculated distance 
            if (isInMinHeap(minHeap, v) && dist[u] != DBL_MAX &&  
                                          (pCrawl->weight)/P_s[v] + dist[u] < dist[v]) 
            { 
                dist[v] = dist[u] + pCrawl->weight/P_s[v]; 

                // update distance value in min heap also 
                decreaseKey(minHeap, v, dist[v]); 
            } 
            pCrawl = pCrawl->next; 
        } 
    }

    free(minHeap->pos);
    free(minHeap->array);
    free(minHeap);
}
```

Comment: Why are you even using `malloc` and `free` in C++? Your code is pure C, apart from `vector<double> at one place. And you are freeing memory allocated in `createMinHeap`, but what about memory allocated via `newMinHeapNode`? *When* did you try to deallocate it so the it gave you an error?

Comment: Given the first comment, do you know the purpose of a `std::vector`?  It seems you do not, since in several places in your code, you're using `C-style` dynamic array creation using `malloc` and `free`.  Why?  Use `std::vector` for this -- that is the entire purpose of `std::vector`, and that is to create dynamic arrays.  You're using `std::vector` already, so it's not a case where you can't use it at all for your assignment.  It's like having a hammer (vector), a bunch of nails, and only using the hammer on just a few of the nails, and then using your hands as a hammer for the other nails.

Comment: This code was taken from the link I put in the initial post. I initially had a simplified implementation with vectors but switched to this one as it was much faster (at least 100 times). I want to free the heap at the end because my main program calls this many times and without the memory leak fixed, it is eventually killed for running out of memory.

Comment: *as it was much faster (at least 100 times).* -- Were you running a debug build instead of a release build?  Your findings of "100 times faster" are impossible unless you're doing something wrong, or you're not running an optimized build.

Comment: Also, you failed to post a `main` function, thus no one is able to duplicate your error.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous comments, this code is pure C, it should not be tagged as C++. Writing it in C++ would make it quite easier to read and to debug. Using `std::vector` would prevent your program from loosing any memory, because memory allocs are encapsulated in this dedicated class.

You may want to follow this tutorial about `std::vector` and object oriented programming : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_stl_tutorial.htm

Generally, `new` and `delete` (C++) are less error prone than `malloc` and `free` (C). They help to avoid some common mistakes (wrong size buffer allocation...)
Classes (C++) have initialisation (constructor) and destruction mechasism that helps to guarantee a valid state, they are a better alternative to C structures...